# MongoDB Script increment the timestamp & Run

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, node-modules

I want one script where it will check every collection with match case and give the count of documents but I want timestamp should be change automatically and script run for every date.

Script:

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection) {
   if (collection.indexOf("collection") > -1){
      count = db[collection].count({"timestamp":{$gte:new ISODate("2017-12-01T23:59:59Z"),$lte:new ISODate("2017-12-02T23:59:59Z")}});
 print("Name:-" + collection + ":");
 print("document:- " + count + ":");}});
```

Here, I want timestamp should change accordingly this script run for full month but daywise.How I can write this in Nodejs? To call the script and change the days accordingly.
Like; Day1 so and so records,so on...

```
      Day1   Day2   Day3
Col1   10     20     15
Col2   20     55     12
Col3   12     45     88
```

Please help.

Comment: `.count`, like every other Mongo command, is async. Printing `count` outside of a callback will never print what you want.

Comment: so how we can do ??

Comment: Well, use a callback of course :) Like any other Mongo (or async operation) in general. something like `db.count( {options}, (error, number) => print(number) )` or `db.count().then( number => print(number) )`, you get the idea

Comment: can u please give some example.I am trying with node only but not able to.Coding is new for me.